# Is there an analytic solution or approximate expression to this integral?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In order to calculate the Fourier transform of a formula as follow:
$$g(x, y) = \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2}{W^2}\right)e^{-il\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})} $$ Where $B$ and $l$ are constants. $$G(f_x, f_y)=\iint g(x, y)\exp\{-2\pi(xf_x +yf_y)\}dxdy$$ Where $F\{\}$ is the Fourier transform.

After transform this formula into cylindrical coordinate system $$ G(R,\Phi) = \iint \exp(-\frac{(R-R_0)^2}{W^2})\exp(-il\Phi))\exp\{-i(\alpha R\sin(\Phi) + \beta R\cos(\Phi))\}RdRd\Phi$$
and then
$$ G(R,\Phi) = \exp(-\frac{R_0^2}{W^2})\iint \exp(-\frac{R^2}{W^2}) \exp(-\frac{R_0R\cos(\Phi)}{W^2}) \exp(-il\Phi))\exp\{-i(\alpha R\sin(\Phi) + \beta R\cos(\Phi))\}RdRd\Phi$$
In this case I don't know how to calculate it.

Or after some attempt I meet a very complex integral and wonder whether there is an analytic solution or an approximate expression to this integral? The expression is as follows:
$$ \mathcal{Z}^{l}_{n}(r, x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{R^2}{W^2}\right) I_{n}\left(\frac{BxR}{W^2}\right) J_{n+l}(rR) RdR$$
where $B$ and $W$ are constants. $J_n$ $I_n$ are Bessel function of the first kind and modified Bessel function of the first kind respectively.

Comment: You didn't tell us what $\mathcal{Z}$ is. In polar co-ords I think you should have $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos\phi$. The angular part of the integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} d \phi \exp({-il\phi+\frac{2rr_0}{w^2}\cos\phi})$ which equals $2\pi I_l(2rr_0/w^2)$ for integer $l$. You then face radial integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty dr \ r I_l(\sqrt{a}r)e^{-r^2/8b}=2e^{ab}\sqrt{2\pi ab^3}\left(I_{l_+}(ab)+I_{l_-}(ab)\right)$ where $l_\pm=(l\pm1)/2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, you are right! Is there a more detailed calculation here? Or if you can give me any guidance for me to figure out this question? Just like this integral equation about $I_l$